# Difference between get_user_model() and importing User from auth

Tags: django, django-models

When I need to use the current user in a model.
lets say I have a model with a current_user field, something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
```

my understanding is User can be fetched either:

1)by importing the current user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

or

2) setting User to:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

I understand both will work if I am not wrong!!

So What is the main difference between those two methods if there is any?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the default `User` model, both approaches will work.

However if you are using a custom user model (or are writing a reusable app), then you should use `get_user_model()` to ensure you get the correct model.

Note that [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) suggest you use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in foreign keys.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
```